# Deleting bucket in supabase storage using c#

Tags: c#, cloud, storage, supabase, bad-request

Im trying to delete my bucket using this code

```
var supabase = new Supabase.Client("url", "key");

            Console.Write("Enter bucket name: ");
            var bucketName = Console.ReadLine();
            var bucket = await supabase.Storage.DeleteBucket(bucketName);
```

But Supabase.Storage.BadRequestException was thrown

I was expecting that it will delete the bucket when the bucket name was entered

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by not having the appropriate permission to perform the deletion.

There are two ways to solve it.

- Use the Service Role Key instead of the Anon key to initialize Supabase
- Set the row-level security policy on storage.buckets from your Supabase dashboard

The first option is simple. The service role key will bypass any row-level security you have set on your Supabase instance, so it will delete the bucket. You want to make sure you don't expose the key publically.

Second option involves you setting up appropriate RLS policies depending on your particular needs.

You can learn more about Supabase storage and its access control here.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/access-control